# Crashlytics asks for dsym files that don’t exist

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

Crashlytics asks for dsym files that don’t exist.

- I’m using Firebase/Crashlytics iOS SDK.
- I notice this happens after I update to Firebase 6.34.0. (Previously 6.28.1)
- I see some crashes get symbolicated correctly for the same version that
  crashlytics asks for missing dsyms. Not sure how this can happen…
- I normally use `fastlane download_dsyms` and `faslane upload_symbols_to_crashlytics` to take care of dsym uploading. Which had worked fine.
- I already tried manually uploading using script `Pods/Firebase Crashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp Config/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios <downloaded_dsyms_dir>` to upload the symbols I downloaded from appstoreconnect.apple.com, waited 24 hours, still doesn’t work.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue, the exact same setup and tried to manually upload as well.